# Generate a unique link for each email id :Yii

Tags: php, email, yii

I have a Yii web app where user can send a mass email. In this mail I would like to send a unique link to each email id. I don't have much idea about how to do this.

Where should I start in order to implement this?

1). How to generate unique links automatically for each email id.

2). How to track the response if the user clicks on the link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you'd need to store the data somehow after each email is sent, with a unique hash. Inside the email you use the unique hash in a URL query.

Then on that page you'd use that hash to call the info stored from that email, for lets say a discussion panel or something.

A simple but effective token can be generated like so:

```
$token = substr( md5( microtime() ), -12 );
```

You can also generate a UNIQUE but Backwards compatible hash with the users email. (this is insecure!)

```
$token = base64_encode ( $email ); // The users email will be encoded
```

You can then use that code to decode and search for that email in a database

```
$emailToken = base64_decode( $_GET['t'] ); // Contains the users email
```

You can test to see if this is a valid token to make it secure against basic injections like so:

```
if ( base64_encode( base64_decode( $_GET['t'] ) ) === $_GET['t'] ) {
    // Valid base64... we hope but is it a valid email?
    $emailToken = filter_var( base64_decode( $_GET['t'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
    if ( filter_var( $emailToken, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
        // Email is valid. Do something to call email info
    }
}
```

Comment: -Can u please tell me where is the url exactly generated? I am initially trying to send some url to a random email(without working with database), I have var_dumped $token but knowing what to do after that

Comment: You need a database in order to save this token to reference later. Whether a flatfile, sqlite, mysql, or the ladder.